# Should we use the OpenData twitter bot to ping people with data related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Reading the latest post on meta, I am wondering if we should / can use the [OpenData twitter account](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/opendata-twitter-feed-stackopendata)  - [@StackOpenData](https://twitter.com/StackOpenData) to ping people with OpenData related question or in quest for a specific data set and invite them to post their question here?

One option would be to have a semi automated (ie. with a human moderation) way to ping people tweeting ["find data on"](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22%22%22find%20data%20on%22%22%22)

This proposition build on the discussion [How to increase site stats](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-to-increase-site-stats/).

Comment: I think it is better to keep the suggestions about twitter bot here to help community managers follow the discussion http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/191/opendata-twitter-feed-stackopendata