# Feature Request: Open Data SE on GitHub for Storing Datasets

Tags: feature-request

wondering if the mods feel like setting up an open data se github account for storing datasets that are created, found, discovered, recreated, etc., from the forum.
or on datahub.io.
or any platform that i'm not thinking of that provides free services for storing data.
i'm not saying the mods need to create the datasets; we could encourage users to do it on their own.
i know i've had a few comments with users (i think are mods) about certain aspects about this before, so hopefully this furthers those chats into fruition.
i think the benefits are endless, mostly in ways that are unclear for everyone at the moment. one lame but relevant example is the built in sharing functionality for datasets in ckan. i've seen the chatter about what to do with the twitter feed before, and this would double its worth in content, as it would be sharing new open data, as well as asking about open data.
that is a very cheesy example, but again, it doubles the scope in content.
also, lame seo point, but having the repo site link here and vice versa, you do get the double dip in search engine coverage.
that is cheesy point number two, however open data is only going to become more of a keyword in the future, and properly applied seo never hurt anyone.
basically, we need a repo. is that possible?

edit:

the github datasets community could be used as well. perhaps this is an answer; we could simply point people here. the only caveat would be to find out exactly what datasets are allowed. i want to say i remember them being more of a worldview than some of the location/society/culturally specific some of our datasets are...
https://github.com/datasets

relevant posts:
[How do I share Open Data with others on this SE site?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/how-do-i-share-open-data-with-others-on-this-se-site)
[Open replacement for cfbstats.com NCAA football CSV's](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3500/open-replacement-for-cfbstats-com-ncaa-football-csvs)
[How to increase Site Stats?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/how-to-increase-site-stats/183)
[OpenData Twitter feed: @StackOpenData](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/opendata-twitter-feed-stackopendata)
[Posting about data sets](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/posting-about-data-sets)

Comment: [See here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10045/27652) for a 4 year old discussion on Stats.SE.

Comment: huh. i never even heard of cross validated se....added my thoughts there, but i think those options are pretty outdated, or not entirely open

Answer (score 2):

Based on our [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4954/1511) + [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/4958/1511) and the ones you linked, I'd like to get the ball rolling.

It's now necessary for publishing on datahub.io to [have an organization](http://blog.datahub.io/2013/10/11/organization-migration-complete/), so I made a [request for one](http://help.datahub.io/discussions/suggestions/703-new-organization-reques) on behalf of OpenData.SE.

---

**Datahub.io organization :: [OpenData StackExchange](http://datahub.io/organization/opendata-stackexchange)**

*Please follow, become a member, or join as an admin!*

Comment: this is great! thanks @philshem! i'm on datahub already but i'll be eyeing this to see it start. this is just the beginning.... ;)